# Perforce command line -> checkout all files in current folder -> do work -> submit all files in current folder (and revert unchanged)

Tags: directory, submit, perforce, checkout

When using the gui, I can right click on a folder, checkout all files in given folder. I can then put them in a new changelist, or leave it to default even if many other files are already in the default changelist.

After doing work, I can right click on the same folder, and submit. I'm then offered a box to give a sensible name to the changelist, which is useful if I didn't bother doing it when checking out. ONLY the files in the folder are submitted (and the unchanged files are reverted).

I want to be able to do the same thing from the command line...Is this possible without having to think and keep track of changelist numbers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When using the gui, I can right click on a folder, checkout all files
>   in given folder.

```
p4 edit ...
```

> I can then put them in a new changelist

```
p4 change
```

By default, the new change includes everything from the default changelist.
Just edit the Files: list if you want to exclude some of them.

> After doing work, I can right click on the same folder, and submit.
>   I'm then offered a box to give a sensible name to the changelist,
>   which is useful if I didn't bother doing it when checking out.

If the files are in the default changelist and you only want to submit the ones from that folder:

```
p4 submit ...
```

If you put them in a numbered changelist, then all its files must be submitted atomically:

```
p4 submit -c CHANGE
```

If you changed your mind about what belongs in that changelist, use `p4 reopen` before submitting.  If you want to update the description, use `p4 change CHANGE`.

> (and the unchanged files are reverted).

```
p4 client
```

Change SubmitOptions from `submitunchanged` to `revertunchanged`.  Now the default submit behavior is to revert unchanged files instead of submitting them.

> Is this possible without having to think and keep track of changelist numbers?

If you just use the default changelist for your open files, you don't need to keep track of anything.  If you do want to use numbered changelists, you don't need to have a photographic memory.

```
p4 changes -s pending --me
```

will show you all of your pending numbered changelists.

```
p4 opened
```

will show you all the files you have opened and what changelist(s) they're open in.